# How to make routes for id and new correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I did it like this:

```
<Route exact path = {`$ {match.url} /`} component = {List} />
<Route exact path = {`$ {match.url} /: id`} component = {View}/>
<Route exact path = {`$ {match.url} / new`} component = {New} />
```

But when I go to the page with **id**, I see two components there
And it is obvious why, because it considers word *new* as **id**

How to do it right?

Comment: which router are you using? in the new one (4) there is a declaration in the component, what did you write there?

Comment: Yes I am using version 4

I just want to find a solution to not show 2 components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it considers word `new` as `id`. Since the path

```
<Route exact path={`${match.url}/:id`} component={View} />
```

shows that a dynamic value is expected at the `id` placeholder. As `id` is just a placeholder using `new` as route parameters will also satisfy the condition.

So you can wrap `Routes` component with `Switch` component and keep the `Route` with `id` placeholder at last. As `Switch` component only renders the first child that matches the path so `View` component will not show up when `/new` is used.

```
<Switch>
   <Route path={`${match.path}/`} component={List} />
   <Route exact path={`${match.url}/new`} component={New} />
   // place route with "id" at last
   <Route exact path={`${match.url}/:id`} component={View} />
</Switch>
```